# Using interface type in a class

Tags: java, class, interface

I'm trying to understand this concept. Where `Path` type is being created using `Paths`'s class method.

I have two doubts:

1. How can we have Path type in class we are creating without any Path interface reference in a class (For ex, implements).

Code snippet:

```
 Path dir = Paths.get(args[dirArg]);
```

The class where I have found this snippet, there is no implementation of Interface Path.

Imported packages in class:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;
import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```

2. In class how can we create a method which returns `Interface` type. For ex `Paths`'s class get method. In `Paths` class there is no link that is connected to `Path` interface. So how its defined in Java ? How can I understand this ?

Please put some light on me...!

Comment: What is class's declared package?

Comment: All imports for that class Mentioned in question ..!

Answer (score 0):

The get-method you call will create (and return) an implementation of your interface.

Let's say you have an interface `Action`:

```
public interface Action {
  void doSomething();
}
```

and you have a call:

```
Action action = X.getAction();
```

With the following X-class:

```
public class X {

  public Action getAction() {
      return new Action() {
          public void doSomething() {
              System.out.println("done");
          };
 }

}
```

So, even though there isn't a specific class that implements `Action`, the `getAction()` method returns an (anonymous) class that implements your interface.

The code is not all that different if there is a class implementing your interface: at that point, the `getAction()` method might return an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we have Path type in class we are creating without any Path interface reference in a class (For ex, implements).

The real answer is, you don't need to care.

The `get` method returns some kind of object that implements `Path`, that's for sure. And you don't need to know any more information about what kind of path that is. All your code need to know is that it returns a `Path`, end of story.

From the outside you might not see a class that implements `Path`, but in fact there must be one. It's just that you don't know.

It is, however, possible to get the actual type of `Path` returned.

```
System.out.println(Paths.get("/Users/").getClass()); // getClass returns the type
```

This prints `class sun.nio.fs.UnixPath`, which does not seem to be a public class.

> In class how can we create a method wich returns Interface type. For ex Paths's class get method. In Paths class there is no link that is connected to Path interface. So how its defined in Java ? How can I understand this ?

You certainly can create a method with an interface return type!

```
interface MyInterface { ... }

class A implements MyInterface { ... }

class B {
    public static MyInterface myMethod() {
        // obviously you can add more logic than this, this is just an example
        return new A();
    }
}
```

Now as a caller of that method,

```
 MyInterface i = B.myMethod(); // you don't (need) know what actual type of object "i" is.
```

Comment: B.myMethod() here creates an object of class A and returns a MyInterface type which is referring to class A object. Correct..? But if we dont have "class A implements MyInterface { ... }", So in this case will it create anonymous class..?